# PhpSpreadsheet - How to retrieve cell values exactly as written in the excel file?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

My goal is to get the unformatted cell values using `$worksheet->toArray()`. What I mean by unformatted is that, the retrieved cell value should look identical to the cell value displayed within the xlsc.

```
$reader = new Xlsx;             
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($filename);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
return $worksheet->toArray();
```

The problem however is that for all cells containing decimals such as `0,5`. The retrieved value is being automatically converted to `0.5`.
I have tried using the following solutions :

Set decimal and thousands operator :

```
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\StringHelper::setDecimalSeparator(',');
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\StringHelper::setThousandsSeparator('.');
return $worksheet->toArray();
```

SetFormatCode :

```
$sheet_dimension = $worksheet->calculateWorksheetDimension();
$worksheet->getStyle($sheet_dimension)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('@');
return $worksheet->toArray();
```

I have also tried doing this with sigular cells like the following :

```
$cellC1 = $worksheet->getCell('AB21'); // contains cell value : 0,5
echo 'Value: ', $cellC1->getValue(), '; location: ', $cellC1->getCoordinate(), PHP_EOL;
// Output : Value: 0.5; location: AB21
```

No matter what I do, the retrieved values of decimals are always separated by a period instead of a comma. How do I go about doing this ?

Comment: CSV? What CSV? If you're reading from a CSV file, you don't need phpspreadsheet. Did you reall mean that, or are you talking about an .xlsx file really? They're extremely different beasts.

Comment: Yes the file that causes the problem is xlsx, although csv can also be processed, sorry about that.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify it

Comment: I have just done so. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: Convert Excel to CSV, but with actual cell value instead of displayed value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73632052/php-convert-excel-to-csv-but-with-actual-cell-value-instead-of-displayed-value)