# PHP: Convert Excel to CSV, but with actual cell value instead of displayed value

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel

I have an Excel file, which I'd like to convert to CSV.
My Excel file has some of its cells formatted, such that `1234.56` is displayed [image].

Problem is, when I convert the Excel file to CSV, using PHPSpreadSheet:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;

$reader = new Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('path_to_excel_file.xlsx');

$writer = (new Csv($spreadsheet))
    ->setEnclosure('')
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
    ->setDelimiter(';');
$writer->setSheetIndex(0);
$writer->save('path_to_csv.csv');
```

The values in the CSV file are stored as  `1234.56 €` (spaces and symbols included), while I want them to be stored as `1234.56`.

I know that in LibreOffice, when converting Excel to CSV, you can specify if you want to store the values *as is* or to keep them formatted.

Any idea on how I can perform this with PHP, ideally using PHPSpreadSheet?

Comment: Look at [phpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) its the replacement for phpExcel an0d has been for some time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the manual, all you need is to set the `Read data only` option before loading the excel sheet.

Check out the updated code below:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Csv;

$reader = new Xlsx();
// set the Read data only option
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('path_to_excel_file.xlsx');

$writer = (new Csv($spreadsheet))
    ->setEnclosure('')
    ->setLineEnding("\n")
    ->setDelimiter(';');
$writer->setSheetIndex(0);
$writer->save('path_to_csv.csv');
```

Reference: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#reading-and-writing-to-file